# get last Call on CallLog using a Service

Tags: android, android-service, android-contentresolver, telephonymanager, calllog

I'm doing a program to send the CallLog to a Server, I created a Service that makes a poll of the telephone status with the following method. This method is called onCreate.

```
private void pollForCallStatus() {
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("Poll", Integer.toString(telephonyManager.getCallState()));
            switch (telephonyManager.getCallState()){
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    Log.d("CallService", "ringing");
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    callStart();
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    callEnd();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
}
```

The method CallEnd, check if the call has started, if its the case its get the duration of this call of the CallLog, I use CallLog because i can't determinate when the outgoing calls starts.

```
private void callEnd() {
    if (isStart) {
        Log.d("CallService", "callEnd");
        Integer duration = getDuration();
        Log.d("CallService", duration.toString());
        Command sender = new SendCall(this.phoneNumber, duration);
        isStart = false;
        this.stopSelf();
    }
}
```

I pasted the method getDuration, I used it to get the duration of the call in CallLog.

```
private Integer getDuration(){
    Integer duration = 0;
    callLogCursor.moveToFirst();
    if ( phoneNumber.equalsIgnoreCase(callLogCursor.getString(callLogCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER))) )
        duration = callLogCursor.getInt(callLogCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION));
    return duration;
}
```

My problem is that getDuration dont get me the last call duration, despite that i recive the  previous call. I tried to wait more time but i receive the same result.

--- Edit ---

I changed the code to use ContentObserver, but i have the same result. I create the Observer on BroadcastReceiver

```
public class CallsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

         ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
         Cursor callLogCursor = cr.query(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER /*sort by*/);

         Command sender = new SendCall(phoneNumber, callLogCursor);
         context.getContentResolver().
            registerContentObserver(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
            true, new CallObserver(context, sender));
    }
}
```

When CallLog change executes the method getDuration, the new getDuration is

```
private Integer getDuration(){
    Integer duration = 0;
    callCursor.moveToFirst();
    if ( phoneNumber.equalsIgnoreCase(callCursor.getString(callCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER))) )
        duration = callCursor.getInt(callCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION));

    Log.d("SendCall.getDuration", duration.toString());
    return duration;
}
```

and the duration of the last call continues wrong, this duration is to the previous call. I don't know that i can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a ContentObserver on call log which will notify you when anything is changed in callLog i.e. if new call is added to call log or you removed the call log

EDIT

Try this get new call log after call finishes I am getting right result with this code

Wait  for 3-4 seconds after call finish and then

```
CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(mActivity,
            CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
managedCursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();


int durationIndex = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);

managedCursor.moveToFirst();

String duration =managedCursor.getString(duration)
```

Comment: ContentObserver notifies me when the callLog changes. But I don´t know if the change is because a call is added or is deleted. And I need to know what is the reason of the change.

Comment: Thanks, my problem was that i created the Cursor before the call had finished.